# Error with -exec in find command

Tags: bash, find

I keep having a problem with tailing some specific files of a same directory on a remote server. Here is my code :

```
ssh host find /path/to/a/dir -name "log*" ! -name "file" -print0 -exec tail -n 20 {} \;
```

It prints `-exec: missing argument`.

Comment: Your `\;` is stripped to `;`, quote your command in its entirety: `ssh host 'find /path/to/a/dir -name "log*" ! -name "file" -print0 -exec tail -n 20 {} \;'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to quote the command argument to ssh i.e.

```
ssh host 'command options, etc., '
```